# XFCE session with GNOME in background

Tags: gnome, xfce, session

I recently installed XFCE on my Ubuntu 10.04 and it runs finely but with an issue.

Everytime I login into my XFCE session I see the background image of GNOME session and after few seconds it disappears which gives me the impression that XFCE session is running over an already running GNOME session.

If that is really the case then it might also be eating into my system's RAM which could be a bug.

All helps and suggestions are welcome.

Comment: This happens to me as well.  Although recently, it hasn't gone away.  See http://askubuntu.com/q/51878/6161 as a potentially related question

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood your question, the background image that you think is of the GNOME session is only the **background image of the GDM** (the graphical login) that will be changed when the desktop envinronment is ready.
So if at the GDM login you choose the XFCE session don't worry : GNOME hasn't started.

Comment: @Stefano it seems you are correct so I'll notice this on next reboot & will let you know.

Comment: @Stefano you were right about GDM background **but** today I got my Ubuntu's GNOME Desktop (with the **wallpaper** I set on GNOME and GNOME **iconset** on Desktop instead of my XFCE Desktop iconset)

Comment: the behavior I have commented above tells that GNOME is running in my XFCE session

Comment: Mmm weird...by the way if GNOME is really running in your XFCE session you should be able to see the two gnome-panels (maybe behind the XFCE's ones).

Comment: @Stefano As I mentioned this behavior is intermittent so the next time when I get such a behavior I'll try hiding the XFCE panel to check GNOME panel (as far as I believe there is no GNOME panel there only GNOME Desktop)

Comment: @Stefano As expected ,there is no gnome-panel only xfce4-panel

Comment: Mmm ok... sincerely i don't know what's happening there, maybe only a bit confusion with the theme. The important is that the gnome-panels don't start.